# 寝ソバしよう meaning (from tweet)

Tags: meaning

寝ソバしよう appeared in a tweet with a picture of soba noodles attached.

Is this trying to say "You will probably sleep well after eating soba"?

Comment: 寝コカコーラゼロしながら読んでます、ってまたスベっちゃった？

Comment: @l'électeur はい、もう羽生結弦くん並みに…。 ps また夜中にそんな体に悪いもん飲んでー！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of us have 「寝酒 (lit:sleep-sake; nightcap) 」  to help us fall asleep.
In the same vein, others might have 「寝ソバ(lit:sleep-soba-noodles; ???)」. Or not.

By the way, "... しよう" usually means "I'll ..." or "Let's ..."

So one possible interpretation may be: "I'll have my night-time soba-noodles so I can sleep well."

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of でしょう、but I didn't think of ましょう。

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggestion. Maybe just reporting he/she is laying down and eating soba.
寝ソバ is not official word.

Comment: Japanese don't have a custom of eating soba before sleeping, but it's easy to cook soba (just boil, it's all process), so the meaning might be "I will eat soba and sleep soon"